# Foreign key won't add

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these two tables but the foreign key won't add. This is the query I'm using but I keep getting cannot add foreign key error. I have also included the Create table statements. Thanks for any help

```
ALTER TABLE courses ADD CONSTRAINT fk_fs FOREIGN KEY (teacher1) 
REFERENCES teachers(fullName) 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `courses` (
`courseID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`courseName` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`module1` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`module2` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`module3` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`module4` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`teacher1` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`teacher2` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`teacher3` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`teacher4` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`courseID`)
 )

 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `teachers` (
`teacherID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`userID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`fullName` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`officeOpen` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
`officeClose` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
`email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`teacherID`)
 )
```

Comment: Do edit the question and add the SQL server you are using (assuming MySQL from the backticks). You also cannot make foreign keys to non-primary key in the table. I assume you are getting an error when trying, please add that too.

Comment: You are trying to add the constraint BEFORE the table creation.Also the parent column needs to be primary KEY or at least unique http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c123ae

Comment: Yes MySQL and I am not adding a foreign key before, the tables have already been added

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen you can make a foreign key to a non-primary key

Answer (score 0):

Foreign keys in MySQL must reference indexed columns. I think what you really want to do is add a foreigh-key column to the "courses" table, ex. fkTeacherID column as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `courses` (
`courseID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`courseName` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`module1` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`module2` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`module3` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`module4` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`teacher1` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`teacher2` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`teacher3` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`teacher4` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
 `fkTeacherID` int(11),
 PRIMARY KEY (`courseID`)
 );

 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `teachers` (
`teacherID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`userID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`fullName` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`officeOpen` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
`officeClose` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
`email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`teacherID`)
 );

ALTER TABLE courses ADD CONSTRAINT fk_fs FOREIGN KEY (fkTeacherID) 
REFERENCES teachers(TeacherID)
```

You can then create a query like:

```
SELECT fullName 
from teachers t
inner join courses c on t.TeacherID = c.fkTeacherID
```

You can then eliminate the teacher1..4 columns. You may also want to the same with modules. You also eliminate the 4 teachers to a course constraint.

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1743a)